# How to pass svn crendentials from jenkin's ui as build parameters?

Tags: svn, jenkins

> I have configure svn account in jenkins, i have set crendentials for
>   svn at global scope in jenkins so that svn can use it.
>
> Now i have one new requirement that whoever run the job of jenkins,
>   has to pass their personal svn crendentials.
>
> Let say 20 uers are using Jenkins jobs and some jobs use SVN url to
>   fetch data from repository i want every user use their personal svn
>   credentials Like user1 has own svn credentials if he is running the
>   job then he should use his own personal SVN's credentials

**Is that possible to pass SVN credentials as build parameters in jenkins job?**

**Is there any other way to acheive that scenario?**

Comment: Could you describe a little more detailed, what you want to achieve here?

Comment: @r4d1um Please see the questions again i have updated